# Rewriting Matrix Equation for Quadratic Programming

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, quadratic-programming

I have a Quadratic Programming problem that looks something like this:

$$
x' = \operatorname{argmin}_{x} \frac{1}{2} x^TPx + q^Tx \\
\qquad \text{subject to} \quad (x - \pi)^Tg \le e
$$

I am planning on using a python library to solve this equation. But, to solve it I need the condition to look like $Ax \le e$. I am a bit rusty with my matrix properties so I was wondering if someone could help me convert $(x - \pi)^Tg \le e$ into $Ax \le e$, where $A$ is dependent on $\pi$ and $g$, but not $x$.

$x, \pi, g \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times 1}$ and $e \in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: Isn't $g^\top x \le e + g^\top \pi$ already in "$Ax \le e$" form?

Comment: yes, thank you. Can't believe I missed that.